# i cannot use my toolbar and drawerlayout with eachother

Tags: android

Hi i want to create my custom toolbar in my layout,but i have a drawerlayout and navigation drawer in that layout too .so when i run my project it say open it again.
this is my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#009000"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>

   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <include layout="@layout/activity_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />


 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

and this is my ActivityMain:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new MyShared(this);
    new Names("first one");
    new Names("second one");
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rec);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new 
    LinearLayoutManager (this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
}
```

this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mehrad.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

and this is my activity_main(Actually its not my main layout.but my main layout include it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rec"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my logcat:

```
 02-16 10:34:14.815: E/AndroidRuntime(4333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-16 10:34:14.815: E/AndroidRuntime(4333): Process: 
 com.example.mehrad.MyApplication, PID: 4333
 02-16 10:34:14.815: E/AndroidRuntime(4333): 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with 
 MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
 02-16 10:34:14.815: E/AndroidRuntime(4333):    at 
 android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1042)
```

Comment: Declare the drawer layout as the root layout..

Comment: inside it keep the linear layout..

Comment: please update if it worked...

Comment: The problem is not clear. Please give us only the segment of the problematic code. Not the whole code.

Comment: i've tried both of them but i have that problem yet

Comment: please help me.